# What kind of memory leaks XCode Analyzer may not notice?

Tags: xcode, debugging, memory-leaks, analyzer

I'm afraid that asking this question may result in some downvotes, but after making some not satisfying research I decided to take a risk and ask more experienced people...

There are many questions here referring to some specific problems connected with the XCode Analayzer Tool. It seems to be very helpful solution. But I would like to ask you - as a beginner in iOS world - what kind of memory management stuff cannot be noticed by this tool.

In other words, are there any common memory management aspects, about which the iOS beginners should think "*Oh, be careful with that, because in this case XCode Analyzer may not warn you about your mistake*"...

For instance, I've found here [Why cannot XCode static analyzer detect un-released retained properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944736/why-cannot-xcode-static-analyzer-detect-un-released-retained-properties) that:

> (...)the analyzer can't reliably detect retain/release issues across
>   method/library boundaries(...)

It sounds like a good hint to consider, but maybe you know about some other common issues...

Comment: Just because a tool can detect a leak does not mean you should not think about memory management less carefully. It's a tool, not replacement of careful thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The analyzer is very good at finding the routine leaks that plague new programmers writing non-ARC code (failures to call `release`, returning objects of the wrong retain count, etc.).

In my experience, there are a couple of types of memory issues it does not find:

- It cannot generally identify [strong reference cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW22) (a.k.a. [retain cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810)). For example, you add a repeating `NSTimer` to a view controller, unaware that the timer maintains a strong reference to the view controller, and if you don't `invalidate` the timer (or do it in the wrong place, such as the `dealloc` method), neither the view controller nor the timer will get released.
- It cannot find circular logic errors. For example, if you have some circular references where view controller A presents view controller B, which in turn presents a new copy of A (rather than dismissing/popping to get back to A).
- It cannot find many non-reference counting memory issues. While it's getting better in dealing with Core Foundation functions, if you have code that is doing manual memory allocations (such as via `malloc` and `free`), the static analyzer may be of limited use. The same is true whenever you're using non-reference counting code (e.g. you use SQLite `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and fail to call `sqlite3_finalize`).

I'm sure that's not a complete list of what it doesn't find, but those are the common issues I see asked about on Stack Overflow for which the static analyzer will be of limited help. But the analyzer is still a wonderful tool (it finds issues other than memory issues, too) and for those individuals not using ARC, it's invaluable.

Having said that, while the static analyzer is an under-appreciated first line of defense, you really should use Instruments to find leaks. See [Locating Memory Issues in Your App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html) in the *Instruments User Guide.* That's the best way to identify leaks.

Comment: Could you illuminate a bit more why it would be bad to `invalidate` your timer in dealloc?

Comment: @MarkBernstein The `dealloc` is only called when there are no more strong references to the view controller. So, because the repeating timer is maintaining a strong reference to the view controller, it will never be called. Putting the `invalidate` in the `dealloc` is analogous to saying "when there are no more strong references to this view controller, go ahead and remove the timer's strong reference to this view controller." You generally put the `invalidate` in `viewWillDisappear` or something like that, depending upon the details of your app.